# What's the latest video card that will work on a 64-bit system?

Tags: 11.04, hardware, graphics, 64-bit

What kind of recent graphics card can I run under Ubuntu 11.04 64-bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/installation-guide/hppa/hardware-supported.html)

Ubuntu's support for graphical interfaces is determined by the underlying support found in X.Org's X11 system. Most AGP, PCI and PCIe video cards work under X.Org. Details on supported graphics buses, cards, monitors, and pointing devices can be found at 
[this link](http://xorg.freedesktop.org/wiki/). Ubuntu 11.04 ships with X.Org version 7.5.

Comment: Where to find this problem's information from xorg? I want to find info about latest graphics card in Nvidia.

Answer (score 1):

The latest cards from ATI (HD 4000 and up) and nVidia (GeForce 8 series and up) all work great with proprietary drivers under 64bit ubuntu, and work reasonably well with open source drivers. Older cards, or certain embedded cards, from nVidia or ATI seem to work much better with the latest open source drivers than they do with proprietary drivers. Intel integrated graphics and some others out there are also very well supported by open source drivers.

In short, the graphics card driver support in 64bit Ubuntu looks pretty much the same as graphics card driver support in 32bit Ubuntu and is pretty good all-around. You'd be hard press to find a card that you can't get decent performance out of with either a proprietary driver or an open source one.

Comment: What you means is I can buy any latest video card which they will all have drivers on ubuntu 11.04?